.NET 6 Azure KeyVault 403 forbidden error
I'm trying to access Azure KeyVault and create Key & Secret using .NET 6.
While running the code, it's throwing an exception 403.
This is the code:
        private ResponseModel<string> CreateVaultSecretInfo(string key, string value)
        {
            ResponseModel<string> result = new();
            try
            {
                var keyVaultName = config["VaultName"];
                var kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";
                var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new ClientSecretCredential(config["tenantId"], config["clientId"], config["secret"]));
                KeyVaultSecret resp = client.SetSecret(key, value);
                logger.LogInformation("created vault secret");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                logger.LogError("exception occured" + ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
            
            return result;
        }


Here is the error:

These are the roles assigned at the Azure Subscription Level:

Registered App under Microsoft Entra Id and given API permissions for that app:

I tried many ways for inserting keys, failed. Could anyone suggest what configuration I'm missing or missed during creating the resource?

Please replace images of code with the actual code. For more information on how to ask good questions that attract answers, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

The error occurs if the calling app registration does not have required roles assigned under Azure Key Vault. Check whether you granted roles to user or application.
I registered one Entra ID application with API permissions granted as below:

Initially, I too got same error when I tried to create secret in Azure Key Vault by authenticating as service principal without assigning role to it:

To resolve the error, make sure to assign proper RBAC role like "Key Vault Administrator" to app registration like this:

When I ran the code again after granting role to application, secret created successfully as below:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

public class VaultService
{
    private readonly SecretClient _secretClient;
    private readonly ILogger<VaultService> _logger;

    public VaultService(string keyVaultName, string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret, ILogger<VaultService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        var kvUri = new Uri($"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net");
        _secretClient = new SecretClient(kvUri, new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret));
    }

    public void CreateSecret(string key, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            _secretClient.SetSecret(key, value);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Secret '{key}' created successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Exception occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddConsole();
        });
        ILogger<VaultService> logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<VaultService>();

        var keyVaultName = "keyvault_name";
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";

        var vaultService = new VaultService(keyVaultName, tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, logger);
        vaultService.CreateSecret("secretName", "secretValue");
    }
}

Response:

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where secret created successfully like this:

